# Prefix and Postfix Operator Challenges in C

Tags: c, prefix

In C, what is the default behaviour for expression `a=b+++c`?
What are other prefix and postfix operators which causes similar challenges for compiler?

Comment: there is no challenge for a compiler here. It's the challenge for the reader..

Answer (score 3):

C11 draft specification, section 6.4, paragraph 4:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence
>   of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

And the example from paragraph 6:

> The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y, which violates
>   a constraint on increment operators, even though the parse x ++ + ++ y
>   might yield a correct expression.

So as [@EugeneSh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh) pointed out, there is no challenge for the compiler, it's only a challenge for the reader.